# Is there any update in wviz (rviz for web)?

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you visit the website of [wviz](http://wiki.ros.org/wviz), one can see that the documentation is really outdated. What really bothers me it is that it doesn't support a bunch of things: **Map, Grid Cells, Path, Pose, Pose Array, Marker Array, Camera**. I want to know if it already supports those features.

Or else, I was wondering if there's either another visualization tool for web (not gazebo simulator, that's not exactly a visualization tool). Or simply if there's another github repository where people continued the development of *wviz* which seems in the documentation the last supported version was fuerte and there's no github repository.

What do you recommend?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235985/is-there-any-update-in-wviz-(rviz-for-web)?/) by [silgon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4085/silgon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 649 on 2016-06-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mohit Arvind Khakharia](https://answers.ros.org/users/38621/mohit-arvind-khakharia/) on 2018-12-11**:
Any new updates for Melodic and Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, there is. Have a look at Robot Web Tools [link text](http://robotwebtools.org/)

---

Originally posted by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) with karma: 620 on 2016-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [silgon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4085/silgon/) on 2016-06-03**:
something a bit more documented? I think you mean mainly **ros3djs**, and it looks not bad. It's the first time I see it. I'll try to test it out.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2016-06-03**:
Looks interesting. But do the demos on the web page work for you? In firefox 46.0.1 on ubuntu 14.04 I only see the grid and one set of coordinate frame axes.

**Comment by [silgon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4085/silgon/) on 2016-06-03**:
I haven't tried yet. But can you tell me which of the github repositories you downloaded? I'm almost certain it is *ros3djs* but I want to be sure. Also because there is no proper documentation.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2016-06-06**:
No download at all, just tried their [online demos](http://robotwebtools.org/demos.html)